# Why is this text-shadow not being applied?

Tags: html, css

The first Click here for a Demo button of this site has text-shadhow applied to it but it doesn't show:

http://www.chineselearnonline.com/ver7

Here's the CSS:

```
   #content .call-to-act a {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: bold;
        color: #ffffff;
            padding: 15px 21px;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            text-align: center;
           }

            background: -moz-linear-gradient(
        top,#e45b2d 0%,#e34e18);
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,from(#e45b2d),
        to(#e34e18));
        -moz-border-radius: 32px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 32px;
        border-radius: 32px;
        border: 1px solid #a04830;
        -moz-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0);
        -webkit-box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0);
        box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(000,000,000,0.5),
        inset 0px 0px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0);
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    }
```

and HTML:

```
    <div class="call-to-act">
        <a href="http://www.chineselearnonline.com/demo/list.html">Click here for a Demo</a>
    </div>
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Its working. On which browser are you facing an issue?

Comment: Working for me on Chrome 31...

Comment: @Nathan Lee Chromium Ubuntu. Strange, I took it from here and I see it in that page: http://css3button.net/

Comment: Its working for me on chrome. - @alexchenco

Comment: works like a charm on FF 26.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see any problem. Works for me in Chrome and Firefox. I noticed in your code an extra `}` maybe thats the problem (but with that the css wouldn't work at all.
P.S. You don't need the `-webkit-` or `-moz-`.